# JavaScript "Script Error", yet again

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cross-domain

In all my web applications, I have a window.onerror() handler in place which sends me a notice of any JavaScript errors via email, in an effort to get my applications completely error-free.

Lately, I am getting more and more of these "Script Error" errors. From similar posts on StackOverflow and other sites, I know that it comes from errors in cross-domain scripts.

However, I do not include any cross-domain scripts. I even adapted my window.onerror() handler to include the list of loaded scripts in its error report (gathered via jQuery $('script[src]')). Still no off-site references.

Now I have read that some browser plugins, such as Google Translate, insert JavaScript scripts into anyone's site and may be causing errors. I blocked Google Translate via meta tag, but there may be a lot of other scripts.

Now, if the (any) browser won't even give me the origin of the script causing the error in order to prepare/account for/adjust/adapt for their errors, I am prepared to block them all. Quid pro quo.

How can I do that?

Thank you for any hint or advice.

Chris.

Comment: You could use the [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Security/CSP) headers to blacklist all other browsers plugins that's inject scripts into your page

Comment: @Christophe,  I'm having the same problem that you had. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @aanders77 No, sorry. I ended up filtering out recurring errors as best I could. It keeps the email notifications manageable, but it's not a solution.

Comment: @Christophe Too bad. There's suprisingly little info to find on this subject.